# How to stop SAPI's execution in run-time mode

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm trying to stop SAPI's execution before End Of Line of reading text from memo at run-time mode when I click  a certain control like a button. how do I do it?.

I tried to interfere SAPI' execution by using timer's execution controlling progressbar that when it reaches position 2, it display a messagedlg while SAPI's execution hadn't reached End Of Line of reading text from memo yet. hoping that SAPI would stop execution, but it disable everything when it's on execution in run-time mode, I can't do anything until it's done reading.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that executing SAPI spech generation blocks your entire application I'm guessing that you are calling it `synchronously` which means that function desen't return untill SAPI has finished reading your text.

[SpVoice Speak method (SAPI 5.4)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ee125647(v=vs.85))

Instead you should call it `asynchronously` which means that function returns imediately and the text is still being read in the bacground.

Thid allows you to continue doing other stuff in your application and amongst other also `Pause`, `Resume` and even `Skip` when you have told SAPI to read multiple streams one after another.